# Is there anyway to move Saved Battle Replays off of a 3DS "SD" Card?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

In Pokemon X and Y, you can save re-plays of your battles to re-view later. They get saved on the consoles "SD" card. Is there anyway to move it off the SD card and put into a video or into a different type of media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, I looked into this a while ago, the replay is not actually a video file, so everytime it is played in game it is being rendered.

Iff you wanted to save the footage you would need to get 3ds capture hardware like http://3dscapture.com/

That is currently the only way that you could save them and use them as a file.

edit: Also just a bonus point, this would be possible if you had a 3ds emulator and the pokemon rom, but until that happens you would need to stick to a capture device. or the good old fashioned camera aimed at your screen(Not recommended).

Comment: I think you mean 'the reply is *not* actually a video file' :)

Comment: Also: If you know someone with a capture device who is willing to record your battle for you, you can share the 'video' publicly and give them the code for them to watch and record

Comment: thanks robotnik you are correct it is what i meant, at work so typing quick lol

Comment: Darn. So it is either A: I spend a decent chunk of money on a 3DS Capture Card or B: Use a camera (never).

Comment: Do *any* games save their replays as actual video files? :p

Comment: I havent come across any, This would be due to video files taking up a lot more space considering most storage is very limited with nintendo products. It is much better to save it as data and re render it each time